# Gradle Installation to create a program using Google Calendar API

Tags: java, gradle, google-calendar-api

I want to create a program in java that helps me gets all the events in my **google calendar**, and somehow *print* it out into a **to-do list**. This is not an application, just a personal weekend project.

I read the **[Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java)**, and I get stuck in the set-up process.

The website instructed me to install Gradle, and get it up and running before I can actually use Google Calendar API.

To install Gradle, I read from: file:///Users/VuThaiHa/Downloads/gradle-2.10/getting-started.html. However, I get stuck in the Environment Variables process on this site. I do not understand what they mean by

> add GRADLE_HOME/bin to your PATH environment variable. Usually, this is sufficient to run Gradle.

On another note, all I want to do right now is to download the jar files of Google Calendar, and use it to fetch all the events in my calendar happening in a specific time frame, and print it out. I have limited time, and I really do not want to get stuck in set-up process. If you can suggest a way to fasten this set-up process for my specific process.

Comment: Please add something you tried yourself.

Comment: Hi Davejal, Thank you for your question. Sorry for the late reply. I actually got help from Colin. He said I can run in my shell: PATH=/Users/VuThaiHa/Downloads/gradle-2.10/bin:$PATH
I think it worked since there were not errors when I imported some libraries in Eclipse. However, I switched to Python instead of Java now, so I am not sure if there are any problems left. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell run `PATH=GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH`. Replace `GRADLE_HOME` with the directory where Gradle resides.

It looks like in your case you would want to do:

`PATH=/Users/VuThaiHa/Downloads/gradle-2.10/bin:$PATH`

`PATH` is a variable that contains the directories your operating system runs executable programs from.

Comment: Thank you so much Colin! I am grateful to your help! I am sorry for bothering you too much, but could you clarify upon where should I find the directories that my operating system runs executable programs from?

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you too much, but could you clarify upon where should I find the directories that my operating system runs executable programs from?
If I want to program in Java, in my workspace directory for this project there are 2 subdirectories: bin and src. So does that mean I have to change PATH to .../workspace/bin for my project? 

Thank you so much for your time! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You don't need to "find the directories that my operating system runs executable programs from" because they are already stored in the `PATH` variable. You just need to add a directory to the `PATH` variable. You do this by running this command in the terminal: `PATH=/Users/VuThaiHa/Downloads/gradle-2.10/bin:$PATH`. If you moved `gradle-2.10` out of your `downloads` folder then adjust the directory in the command accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much Colin! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I am really sorry for this late reply!. Yes. It worked. However, I decided that I would try to implement my program in Python instead of Java, so right now I am still working in my Python Code. Thank you so much Colin for your help!